# Not able to set a current_user using Authlogic on Rails 3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I had the official authlogic plugin running perfectly on Rails 2.3.5. I converted my application to Rails 3.0.1 and now I'm having some problems.

I've included the following authlogic gem in my gemfile
`gem 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'`

When a user logs in, the session is saved. When calling that user session, the returned value is nil. `UserSession.find returns a nil value` so I'm not able to assign a current_user.

sessions_controller.rb

```
  def create
   @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
   if @user_session.save!
    flash[:notice] = 'Login successful'
    redirect_to root_url
   else
    render :action => 'new'
 end
  end
```

application_controller.rb

```
 helper_method :current_user, :current_user_session

 private

  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end
```

When a user logs in, the flash notice is returned with `'Login sucessful'` but the current_user isn't set. I've also tried this with the official authlogic plugin and nothing changed. Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this exact problem. For some reason it was interfering with basic auth - to fix it I set allow_http_basic_auth to false.

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base

  allow_http_basic_auth false

end
```

Comment: Wow this works like a charm! I've been trying to figure this out all day. I wish I could upvote you more. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yes, this solved it for me, too. UserSession.find always returned nil.

Comment: my god! i had been struggling with this all day.