# Rails 3 - Authlogic...ARGH

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

Have looked for a solution for 2 days now and am beating my head against the wall.  I have tried both the normal authlogic build and the fork

authlogic or 'authlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/odorcicd/authlogic.git', :branch => 'rails3'

I have everything working except for when I create a UserSession it will not take the current_account details, so I"m left with every login will allow you to log into any of the subdomains.  I can't seem to find a solution for this issue

`def new
@user_session = @current_account.user_sessions.new
  end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for (from [Not able to set a current_user using Authlogic on Rails 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067641/not-able-to-set-a-current-user-using-authlogic-on-rails-3-0-1))

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
   allow_http_basic_auth false
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I gave that a go and still the queries that were running didn't join the tables correctly.  Although I would love to fix it, my deadline is too tight to mess with it.  I hope in the future someone will patch authlogic for good but for now with Devise and it is AWESOME...happy with my decision

Comment: @bokor Was this only marked as correct because you changed your mind on what you were going to do?