# Calling a method for current_user when logging in using authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I am using `authlogic` for authentication in my rails app. I need to be able to call a method for the current_user when they sign in but it's returning nil.

In my user_sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

  if @user_session.save
    current_user.increment_login_count_for_current_memberships!
    flash[:notice] = 'Sign in successful.'
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

And it's returning...

```
Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `increment_login_count_for_current_memberships!' for nil:NilClass
```

I've seen a similar problem here [Not able to set a current_user using Authlogic on Rails 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067641/not-able-to-set-a-current-user-using-authlogic-on-rails-3-0-1) where the answer was to disable `basic_auth`, but I am using `basic_auth` for my admin side of the app so I cannot simply disable it.

- Why can't I call the `current_user` here?
- If I can't call `current_user` here, is there a way to set it?

Comment: what errors do you get if you use `@current_user` instead of `current_user` ?

Comment: I get the same errors as in my original post using `@current_user`

Comment: Does it work if you use `@user_session.user`?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your problem in order to debug. Which rails and ruby versions are you using?

Comment: Ruby 1.9.2 & Rails 3.2.1

Comment: And which version of authlogic? See your `Gemfile.lock` if not sure.

Comment: Very strange. current_user works well for me. In Rails 3.0.1 and 3.2.1, with ruby 1.8 and ruby 1.9. With authlogic 2.1.6 and 3.1.0. Can you push some source to github that makes me able to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why I cannot call `current_user` or `@current_user` here.  But I found two ways to call the current_user here in the controller code...

```
UserSession.find.user.increment_login_count_for_current_memberships!
```

and

```
@user_session.user.increment_login_count_for_current_memberships!
```

If anyone wants to shed some light on why I can't call `current_user` here, I'll happily award you the bounty :)

Comment: That's not an answer to your own question.

Comment: It is a solution to my problem though and therefore answers the second part of my question.

Answer (score 2):

In my own app, I have these two methods (among others) defined in `lib/authlogic_helper.rb` (and I'm assuming you do too):

```
module AuthlogicHelper
  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
  end
end
```

Those methods seem to do exactly what the code in your answer does, except that the user session instance variable is called `@current_user_session` instead of `@user_session` as it is in your controller code.

If you rename your user session variable to `@current_user_session` in your controller action, then the `current_user_session` method will short-circuit and return the session you just created, which should then allow the `current_user` method to return the correct user.

Comment: In my app these are defined in my application controller. I couldn't get your answer to work for me but I appreciate the advice (hence the bounty awarded!)

Comment: Honestly, even if that had worked, it's very hacky to depend on the name of an instance variable defined in another module. Your solution is cleaner and more explicit.